Extracting Data From Website (Javascript/VB.net)
I am trying to extract the total number of online users for a discord server. If I use the web version, you can see its located like this:
<h3 class="membersGroup_cbd271 container_a5ad5c text_a5ad5c">
   <span class="hiddenVisually_a98a7c">Online, 2,572 members</span>
   <span aria-hidden="true">Online — 2572</span>
</h3>

So, I have a timer that checks:
Private Sub OnTimerTick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim browserTab = browser.ElementAt(0)

    If browserTab IsNot Nothing AndAlso browserTab.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame Then
        Dim jsCode As String = "
            (function() {
                // Extract the number of online users between 'Online,' and 'members'
                const memberText = document.querySelector('div[role=""list""][aria-label=""Members""]')?.textContent.trim();
                const match = memberText ? memberText.match(/Online,\s*([\d,]+)\smembers/) : null;
                const onlineUsers = match ? match[1] : 'Unknown';

                return { onlineUsers: onlineUsers };
            })();"

I then reference is as such:
Dim onlineUsers As String = "Unknown Online Users"
    
Me.Invoke(New Action(Sub()
                         Try
                             onlineUsers = result.onlineUsers
                         Catch ex As Exception
                             onlineUsers = "Unknown Online Users"
                         End Try
    
                         lblOnlineUsers.Text = onlineUsers

However, when I run it - it just says "Unknown". The JS seems to work when I run it in the console, on a browser. Any idea why - I assume my vb.net code is wrong?
